# How to clear all Groups And Items in Listview Control

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How to clear all Groups And all Items in that Groups in Listview Control

Answer (score 0):

Probably [ListView.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear.aspx) will work for you. And to clear groups in ListView call [ListViewGroupCollection.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewgroupcollection.clear.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you are filling your group items with datasource then you could try something like this..

How about

```
 DataSource = null;
 DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the listViewItems which are grouped, you can do following:

```
        foreach (var group in listView.Groups)
        {
            var listViewItemsToDelete = listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(item => Equals(item.Group, group));
            foreach (var itemToRemove in listViewItemsToDelete)
            {
                listView.Items.Remove(itemToRemove);
            }
        }
        listView.Groups.Clear();
```